# How can I loop though some columns and all rows, and if the value is nan, fill that value with values of other column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I am new to Python. I have a dataframe with the following columns: State, City, Lat and Long. Some of the cities do not have a value for Lat neither Long, so I wanted to use the mean of the Lat and Long to fill those nan.
I created two columns that show the mean of those two fields according to the State where the city is located.

```
grouped_State = df.groupby(["State"])
long_State = grouped_partido["Long"].mean()
lat_State = grouped_State["Lat"].mean()

data = df["State"],df["Lat"],df["Long"]
headers = ['State', "Lat_city","Long_city"]

df_x = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)
df_x = pd.merge( left = df_x, right = long_partido , how = "left",
              left_on = "State", right_on = "State")
df_x = pd.merge( left = df_x, right = lat_partido , how = "left",
              left_on = "State", right_on = "State")
```

The result would be something like this:

```
Index  State  Lat_city  Long_city  Lat     Long
  0      A      -34       -56     -34.6    -56.1
  1      B      nan       nan     -33      -54.2
  2      A      nan       nan     -34.6    -56.1
  3      B      -35.3     -55.5   -33      -54.2
```

The output I am trying to get would be like this:

```
Index  State  Lat_city  Long_city  Lat     Long
  0      A      -34       -56     -34.6    -56.1
  1      B      -33      -54.2    -33      -54.2
  2      A      -34.6    -56.1    -34.6    -56.1
  3      B      -35.3     -55.5   -33      -54.2
```

I have been trying with different kinds of loops and experimented with lambda functions, but nothing worked as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the data frame documentation, located at (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)
 .fillna excepts a series as well. So if you were to do -

```
df['Lat_city'] = df['Lat_city'].fillna(df['Lat'])
df['Long_city'] = df['Long_city'].fillna(df['Long'])
```

You would get the expected output -

```
 Index  State  Lat_city  Long_city  Lat     Long
  0      A      -34       -56     -34.6    -56.1
  1      B      -33      -54.2    -33      -54.2
  2      A      -34.6    -56.1    -34.6    -56.1
  3      B      -35.3     -55.5   -33      -54.2
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could do somehting like this with groupby, and fillna().

```
df['Lat_city'] = df['Lat_city'].fillna(df.groupby(['State'])['Lat'].transform('mean'))
df['Long_city'] = df['Long_city'].fillna(df.groupby(['State'])['Long'].transform('mean'))

print(df)
        State   Lat_city    Long_city   Lat     Long
    0   A      -34.0      -56.0        -34.6    -56.1
    1   B      -33.0      -54.2        -33.0    -54.2
    2   A      -34.6      -56.1        -34.6    -56.1
    3   B      -35.3      -55.5        -33.0    -54.2
```